Density of a set in a sphere of a normed vector space
I have being bugged for a while with the following problem.
Consider a compact set $X$ in $\mathbb R^d$. The class of bounded functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ can be endowed with the sup norm $\|\cdot\|$. The fact that $\|f\|=1$ does not mean that there is a point in $X$ where $|f|=1$, just that there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ converges to $1$ or $-1$. Hence, in the sphere $S=\{f:\|f\|=1\}$ there can be functions that are everywhere strictly smaller than one. Now, consider the set $U=\{f:\exists x \text{ where } f(x)=1\}.$ If I am not wrong, this set is dense in $S$. Indeed, fix $f\in S$, and assume that $\sup f=1$ (the case $\inf f =-1$ is analogous...). For each $n$, I must have a non-empty set $C_n\subseteq X$ where $f\geq 1-1/n$. I define $f_n = f$ on $X\setminus C_n$, and $1$ on $C_n$. Clearly, $\|f_n-f\|\leq 1/n$, so $f_n\to f$. Moreover, $f_n\in U$, so $f$ must be in the closure of $U$.
Now, if we restrict to Borel measurable functions, this is still true (note that all the $U_n$ will be measurable if $f$ is, so $f_n$ will be measurable). In such a case, the sup norm can equivalently be defined as $\|f\|=\sup_{\mu\in M^1_X}\langle\mu,f\rangle$, where $M^1_X$ is the set of all the Borel measures on $X$ with total variation at most one. Indeed, this set contains all the Dirac masses, and so if $\|f\|\leq 1$ it must be that $|f|\leq 1$ everywhere.
Now, there are several other possible subsets $H\subseteq M^1_X$ such that $\phi(f)=\sup_{\mu\in H}\langle \mu,f\rangle$ defines a norm. I guess that sufficient conditions would be that $H$ separates the space of bounded measurable functions (so that $\phi(f)=0$ implies $f=0$), and that $-H\subseteq H$ (to ensure that $\phi(\alpha f)=|\alpha|\phi(f)$). Let again $U=\{f:\exists\mu\in H\text{ s.t. }\langle\mu,f\rangle=1\}$ and $S=\{f:\|f\|=1\}$. What are (hopefully not too strong) conditions on $H$ such that $U$ is dense in $S$?
A trivial condition is to ask that $H$ is sequentially compact (wrt the absolute variation norm). For any $f\in S$ I have a sequence $\mu_n$ of measures in $H$ such that $\langle \mu_n, f\rangle\to 1$, and by compactness I can consider a subsequence that converges to $\mu^\star\in H$. In particular, convergence in total variation implies that $\langle\mu_\star,f\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle\mu_n,f\rangle=1$. So $f\in U$, meaning that $U$ and $S$ coincide. However, this is clearly not the general case, as $M^1_X$ is not compact under the total variation topology, for a general compact set $X$.
If this would make the question easier, I would also be interested in cases where $U$ is dense in $S$ in a weak sense, namely, there is only a point-wise convergent sequence of functions in $U$ that converges to every function in $S$.
Remark.
Note that if one restricts to the case of continuous functions, then things should be easier. If I remember well $M_X^1$ is weakly compact, meaning that any subset $H$ of $M_X^1$ that is closed under the weak topology on $M_X$ is weakly compact. In particular, if we have a sequence $\mu_n$ in $H$ such that for some $f\in S$ we have $\langle \mu_n,f\rangle\to1$, I can always find a weakly converging subsequence. Now the continuity of $f$ implies that $P\mapsto\langle P, f\rangle$ is continuous (under the weak convergence topology), and so I have a $P^\star\in H$ such that $\langle P^\star, f\rangle =1$. So, if I am not wrong, the restriction of $S$ to continuous functions coincides with the restriction of $U$ to continuous functions, whenever $H$ is closed under the weak topology. However, I am specifically interested in the case where discontinuous functions are allowed.
